# apply in Common Lisp: is the function called once, or once for every element of the list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to fully understand the way apply works, but cannot find a clear enough explanation... Given this:

http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_a.htm#apply

and this:

http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm

Suppose I do the following:

```
(defun sum (L)
  (apply #'+ L))
```

and then call the following:

```
(sum '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

does it do the following:

```
(+ 1 2 3 4 5)
```

or the following:

```
(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 (+ 4 5))))
```

In other words, if I write the following function:

```
(defun sum2 (L)
  (if (null L)
      0
      (+ (first L) (sum2 (rest L)))))
```

is it exactly equivalent as my function above with apply?

Comment: As well as Rainer's answer note that your `sum` function may be different than `+` in other, more obscure ways.  This is because an implementation is free to play some tricks with operations like `+`: it could, for instance evaluate `(+ 1.0 1 2.0 3)` as `(+ (+ 1 3) (+ 1.0 2.0))`, or `(+ 3 a b 6)` as `(+ 9 a b)`.  (But note arguments must be evaluated left to right: reordering of operations, if it happens, happens after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(apply #'+ '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

is basically the same as

```
(+ 1 2 3 4 5)
```

Note that in Common Lisp argument lists usually have limited length. The max argument list length depends on the implementation and can be as low as 50. See the variable `call-arguments-limit`.

If you want to add larger lists of numbers use `reduce`:

```
(reduce #'+ '(1 2 3 4 5))
```